# Tool windows gone

Tags: edit-mode

Where are the tool option windows that are supposed to popup? I use Inset Faces and there's no window where I can choose Even offsets. The status bar at the bottom of the screen says that right clicking will bring up the Call Menu, but that's been set to escape from the tool. So, how many versions back do I need to go before this was broken?

Version 3.4.1

Answer (score 1):

The options should be in the *Operator Panel* (the little expandable tab that pops up in the bottom left after an action - insetting for example). There is a checkbox for even offsets:

[image: Offs]

Comment: That window isn't showing up. They've moved it to the header, but it'll only show if you click the tool icon, not if you use a shortcut key while a different tool is active, such as Select. I've reported the bug. Every time they change the interface they break it in major ways. I wish they'd at least test this stuff first.